# Shut off valve still leaking after being replaced

Tags: valve, shutoff, leaking

I just replaced the entire shut off valve for my toilet and its still leaking.  I used all new parts.  Would could be the issue?

Comment: Probably one or more of the connections are leaking.  Find where leak is coming from, and either try to tighten connection or disassemble and use tape or pipe paste to seal connections.

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen - or in other words, *show us what you're seeing* because there are many things which could have gone wrong.

Comment: leaking how/where?

Comment: I am going to try the tape and see if that fixes the issue.  I think it will as I found a video that shows that needs to be done ant its exactly on the spot that is leaking.  Thank you for the replies. very helpful!